# Cant see mnemonics on ollydbg 2.01

Tags: x86, assembly

Im reverse engineering an exe, but i get locked on a specific location, i suppose this is a jump to the same location, when im on this "obfuscated" addresses i cant see any instruction, but the actions looks like be **JMP** and **RDTSC**.

Its bad configured **OllyDBG** ?

Bug ?

Some type of protection like **VirtualProtect** from MSDN ?

Im using **Windows 7 on VirtualBox**.

[image]

Comment: 7f fe is jg eip  if  either zero flag or signed flag is set /unset this  will keep on jumping to the same location  and also specify which version of ollydbg you are using 2 or1

Comment: @blabb yes i know, the opcodes are easy to get here http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x7F, but my question is why happens that, why doesn't show me the instructions, on some parts happen this and search instruction by instruction for 30000 lines its hard too. If i have instructions i can fully understand, but search by opcodes.. and the version used is 2.01, i wrote on title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes OllyDbg analysis of the code is incorrect and it shows data bytes instead.
This may happen if the segment of code you are looking at has no direct call/jmp into.

If you right-click in the CPU window and select "Remove analysis from module" it will force everything in the disassembly window show as instructions.